Why can`t I see my object through refractive surface (Cycles)
I am probably missing something very simple. The hdri background can be seen through the water (a simple refractive material), but the object can`t. This is the same for world materials both with or without volumetrics.


I assume that you have EEVEE enabled.
In EEVEE to make refraction work you should:

Turn on Screen Space Reflection and Refraction in World settings:



Turn on Raytrace Refraction in each refractive material:



Sorry for the confusion; it`s all Cycles.

Are you sure? It doesn't look like cycles.

Yes, I am sure :)

have you tried different IOR?

Normally that shouldn't be necessary if it's really accurate; but, yes when I decrease ior it gets a little more transparent (obviously) for the background; but the object still is 0 visible.
